# Is there any way to get bytes data from specific range in excel office JS?

Tags: excel, office-js, binary-data, arraybuffer

In my project I need to print the excel sheet from specific range. can we get bytes array using specific range from the worksheet?

Getting whole worksheet pdf binary data using the [getFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=common-js-preview#office-office-document-getfileasync-member(1)) method but, I need only specific range binary data.

Comment: Thanks for reaching us.  We don't have this feature yet.

For new feature request, we would like to suggest you go to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform and see if your question has already been asked or ask a new question. Feature requests on it are considered when we go through our planning process.